# CSS Hierarchy div>table>td>id>class

Tags: css, html-table, hierarchy

I want to target the "order_bar_active" class but I'm not getting the right hierarchy.

```
<div class="order_bar">
<table class="order_bar">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td id="adress_data_bar" class="order_bar_active">
</td></tr></tbody></table></div>
```

**Edit**: The `class="order_bar_active"` is not unique, so I need to define it using the unique `id="adress_data_bar"`.

EDIT #2: The solution for my specific problem is:

```
table.order_bar #adress_data_bar.order_bar_active {
}
```

Comment: simply `#adress_data_bar` or `.order_bar .order_bar_active {...` or `div.order_bar .order_bar_active {...` or `table.order_bar .order_bar_active {...`

Comment: so what's the problem with just `#adress_data_bar {...`  ??

Comment: your edit#2 is unnecessary. `id` is supposed to be unique and hence no need for that selector. just `#adress_data_bar {...` will suffice.

Answer (score 3):

In your example the `order_bar_active` class is the only one of it's kind so you simply need

```
.order_bar_active {
  your rules
}
```

Further to your edit that `order_bar_active` is not unique, you can append the class name to the unique ID like so:

```
#address_data_bar.order_bar_active {
  your rules
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately #address_data_bar.order_bar_active doesn't respond, that's why I came to the conclussion that I have to add more hierarchic informations, which I am struggeling to implement due to complexity of the hierarchy. EDIT: Added the solution which came through your help! thank you.